# Could BFS be implemented using recursion?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I'm a green hand in coding and C++ programing(so is English).I'm trying to implement BFS of graph by using recursion. However, may I write some bugs leading to some errors.I want to know whether it can be implemented and how to do it? Here are my codes:

Note that :

1. ***w*** is the node wanting to find;
2. ***n*** represent the quantity of node;
3. ***sunshine*** represent the present node;
4. ***T*** represent the sum of every data of node which has been read;
5. ***Time*** represent an array storaging the sum of data through different path to the aiming node.

I will appreciate it if you tell you the answer or help me optimize my code.

Please be patient！ (｡･ω･｡)

---

```
 void bfs(int G[][1001], int w, const int n, int sunshine, long long T, int visited[], int* count, long long Time[])
{
    if (sunshine == w)
    {
        Time[*count] = T;
        (*count)++;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (G[sunshine][i] != -1 && visited[i] == 0)
        {
            T += G[sunshine][i];
            visited[i] = 1;
            bfs(G, w, n, i, T, visited, count, Time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question properly.

Comment: _w is the node wanting to find_ I recommend using meaningful names to make the code more readable.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to visit *all* the neighbours before you start recursing into them.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.
Thanks!  I try it but in vain.  I do not know how to edit and format it!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.